# Multi-level answers depending upon previous query

Tags: html, random, multi-level

I am trying to create a question and answer quiz, depending upon previous question. So if the user clicks yes, the previous question disappears from the screen and a new question is displayed on the screen, a different question if no is clicked. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Is the answer to this question Yes or No?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Yes</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">No</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction1() {
}
function myFunction1() {
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is by using the display css property like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="first-question">
      <p>Is the answer to this question Yes or No?</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction('first-question', 'second-question-1')">Yes</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction('first-question', 'second-question-2')">No</button>
    </div>
    <div id="second-question-1" style="display: none;">
      <p>You have clicked "Yes"</p>
      <p>Return to the first question ?</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction('second-question-1', 'first-question')">Yes</button>
      <button onclick="">No</button>
    </div>
    <div id="second-question-2" style="display: none;">
      <p>You have clicked "No"</p>
     <p>Return to the first question ?</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction('second-question-2', 'first-question')">Yes</button>
      <button onclick="">No</button>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction (hide, show) {
        document.getElementById(hide).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

UPDATE : use only 1 function

Comment: this looks exactly like what I am looking for, but what happens if I need 5 levels of questions? so the number of questions become 2^n (n is the level)?

Comment: Well... You will have a many div elements, with many id. You could use only one js function by sending the id in parameter.

Comment: function myFunction3() {
       document.getElementById("first-question").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("second-question-2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("third-question-1").style.display = "block";
      }

Still shows the 2nd question.

Comment: It should not. Can you send me your full code? By the way I have edited my first post, you can use only one function.